# Найти каждое N-ое вхождение

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Имеется список ФИО, пример:

```
Иванов Иван Иванович  
Петров Петр Петрович  
Сидоров Сидор Сидорович
```

Задача:
после имени (в позицию каждого второго пробела) поставить символ `;`

Результат:

```
Иванов Иван;Иванович  
Петров Петр;Петрович  
Сидоров Сидор;Сидорович
```

Реализовать с использованием регулярных выражений, без привязки к какому-либо языку программирования (замена в NOTEPAD++).

Задание гораздо сложнее, но я уже разобрался, ответ внизу.

Comment: @out, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Вроде корректный и хороший вопрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нашёл верное решение, спасибо [@ToolTip](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/28/tool-tip).
В NP++
Найти `^(\S+)\ (\S+)\ (\S+)$`
Заменить на `\1 \2;\3`

Answer (score 2):

```
var str   = 'Иванов Иван Иванович';
var regex = /^([^\ ]+)\ ([^\ ]+)\ ([^\ ]+)$/;
str = str.replace(regex, "$1 $2;$3");
document.write(str)​;
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/dkuWp/).

Comment: Нет, не совсем то (программно могу вообще без регулярного выражения).
Нужна реализация ТОЛЬКО с помощью регулярного выражения (поиск второго пробела в строке).
Ctrl+H в Notepad++.